# Spark UDF: Apply np.sum over a list of values in a data frame and filter values based on threshold

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, spark3

Very knew to using spark for data manipulation and UDF. I have a sample df with different test scores. There are 50 different columns like these. I am trying to define a custom apply function to filter values (total counts in each row) which are greater than 80.

test_scores

[65, 92, 96, 72, 70, 85, 72, 74, 79, 10, 82]

[59, 81, 91, 69, 66, 75, 65, 61, 71, 85, 69]

Below is what I am trying:

```
customfunc = udf(lambda val: (np.sum(val > 30)))

df2 = (df.withColumn('scores' ,customfunc('test_scores')))
```

Getting the below error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'str'
```

Comment: I think you might want to take a look into [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Edit: I think I misunderstood your question. Is `'test_scores'` as tuple? Because it seems like you are comparing `tuple` with `str`, and I am assuming that `scores` is a `tuple` and `test_scores` is a `string`.

Comment: @FelipeWhitaker 'test_scores' is a column in a larger dataframe and each row has a series of scores

Comment: Can you try `df2 = df.withColumn('scores' ,customfunc(df2.select('test_scores')))`?  I don't know if your can give a column name directly to an `udf`.